# MySQL - query to get specific result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have started learning MySQL and I'm stuck on a case.

I have the following table:

```
id | value
1  | abc
1  | def
2  | 
2  | 
3  | pqr
3  | 
4  |
4  | xyz
5  |
```

Please note the empty values beside numeric int denotes empty strings.

**Problem statement**: I need to get those ids which if formed into a group would only have empty strings attached to it. Example here would be ids: 2, 5

**Explanation:** id = 2 appears twice both with empty strings and hence included. id = 5 appears once and have one empty string, thus included. id = 3 is not included since one of its instance has got non-empty value i.e. "pqr"

I am stuck with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 GROUP BY id;
```

But this gives a wrong result.

Could you please help me out? What should be the query to get ids = 2, 5. I am sorry for the table formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 t1d ON t1d.id = t1.id AND t1d.value <> ''
WHERE t1d.id IS NULL
```

without `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` = one happy database!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected outcome with conditional counting compared to counting of all rows within a group:

```
 select id from t1
 group by id
 having count(*)=count(if(`value`='',1,null))
```

`count(*)` returns the number of records with the corresponding id. `count(if(`value`='',1,null))` return the number of such records, where the `value` field is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Using below query you will get your desired output.

```
select id 
from test_empty 
group by id 
having TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM group_concat(value))=""
```

> By `group_concat(value)` output will concatenated  value by comma for all the ids.
>
> By using `TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM group_concat(value))` trailing comma can be removed
>
> By using `having` we can place condition on group by that only id with all blank value will be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

An empty string will always be "less than" any non-empty string, so this should do the trick:

```
 select id from t1
 group by id
 having max(value) = ''
```